# accumulative recursive function to produce a list of subtotals from last to first

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, racket, subtotal

Trying to do this `'(3 2 1)` -> `'(6 3 1)` with accumulative recursion
I can get the result (sort of) that I desire, what I mean is that my firsts and rests seem to be in the right order but my `(cons` expects a list and I give it a number. Any help is appreciated.

If I replace `(cons` with `(list` in the helper and I `(reverse` the `li` variable in the function I get the `'(6 3 1)` that I would like but with `(list (list (list '()` in front. I would just like `'(6 3 1)`

This is what I have

```
(define (subtotal li)
  (subtotal-help (reverse li) 0))

(define (subtotal-help li acc)
  (cond
    [(empty? li) empty]
    [else
      (list 
        (subtotal-help (rest li)
                       (+ (first li) acc))
        (+ (first li) acc))]))
```

Running `(subtotal li)` produces `'(((() 6) 3) 1)`, and with `cons` is produces `'(((() . 6) . 3) . 1)`. I need just `'(6 3 1)`.

Comment: @exnihilo  It's a question for class. The prof wants an accumulator style helper function. I'm supposed to add 0 to 1 and 1 to 2 and 2 to 3 and produce the list. I am new to programming

Comment: @exnihilo A little bit. The prof is all over the place and with the campus shutdown, the class is online. Thus, he's even more confusing, as he doesn't teach anything new. I thought sub-total calling itself first meant it was in tail position. I'll have to do some more research. I'm pretty much teaching myself.

Comment: @exnihilo the accumulator is for keeping track of the sum, not the output list. I don't think it's a requirement to write a tail-recursive solution.

Comment: @JezzLess I'm not sure what you mean by "accumulative recursion". Is it "tail recursion"? if that's a requirement, then take a look at my second solution. Otherwise use the first one

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Yeah, that's what I mean. Accumulative recursion was thrown around there somewhere. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `cons` to build an output list, not `list`. Your code is close to being correct, we just need to shuffle things around and add one extra `reverse` at the end:

```
(define (subtotal li)
  (reverse
   (subtotal-help (reverse li) 0)))

(define (subtotal-help li acc)
  (cond
    [(empty? li) empty]
    [else (cons (+ (first li) acc)
                (subtotal-help (rest li) (+ (first li) acc)))]))
```

But if you really want a tail-recursive solution, then it takes a bit more of work:

```
(define (subtotal li)
  (cond
    [(empty? li) empty]
    [else (let ((lst (reverse li)))
            (subtotal-help (rest lst) (list (first lst))))]))

(define (subtotal-help li acc)
  (cond
    [(empty? li) acc]
    [else (subtotal-help (rest li)
                         (cons (+ (first li) (first acc))
                               acc))]))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(subtotal '(3 2 1))
=> '(6 3 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fine answer by @ÓscarLópez answers the immediate question of OP, but there are other ways to solve the problem which may not be exactly what OP's professor is looking for.

One could `map` over the input list together with a range of indices into the list, using `drop` to reduce the list for each `apply` which sums the remaining list. Here `_x` is the (ignored) value taken from the input list by `map`, `n` is the number of elements to `drop`, and `xs` is the input list:

```
(define (subtotal-list xs)
  (map (lambda (_x n)
         (apply + (drop xs n)))
       xs
       (range (length xs))))
```

```
scratch.rkt> (subtotal-list '(3 2 1))
'(6 3 1)
scratch.rkt> (subtotal-list '())
'()
```

Incidentally, Common Lisp has a nice idiom for this sort of thing that works similarly using the `LOOP` macro. Here `x` takes not elements from the list `xs`, but rather the whole list, and at each iteration `x` is reduced by using `cdr` (by default):

```
(defun subtotal-list-cl (xs)
  (loop
     :for x :on xs
     :collect (apply #'+ x)))
```

```
SCRATCH> (subtotal-list-cl '(3 2 1))
(6 3 1)
SCRATCH> (subtotal-list-cl '())
NIL
```

Getting back to the assignment at hand, if an iterative helper procedure is required, and if `apply` is allowed, then a more concise version of the tail-recursive procedure can be defined. Here, since the intermediate results are `cons`ed onto the front of the accumulator, the accumulator must be reversed at the end:

```
(define (subtotal-list-iter xs)
  (subtotal-list-helper xs '()))

(define (subtotal-list-helper xs acc)
  (if (null? xs) (reverse acc)
      (subtotal-list-helper (rest xs)
                            (cons (apply + xs) acc))))
```

```
scratch.rkt> (subtotal-list-iter '(3 2 1))
'(6 3 1)
scratch.rkt> (subtotal-list-iter '())
'()
```

Answer (score 0):

Relaxing the explicit recursion bit, a natural way to traverse a list in right to left order (And build up a new one in the same order) is to use a [right fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) (Typically implemented with recursion, though that's hidden from the caller).

Example using [`for/foldr`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffoldr%29%29):

```lisp
(define (subtotal lst)
  (for/foldr ([total 0]
              [totals '()]
              #:result totals)
    ([n (in-list lst)])
    (let ([new-total (+ total n)])
      (values new-total (cons new-total totals)))))
```

or if you prefer [`foldr`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) instead of the `for` macro:

```lisp
(define (subtotal lst)
  ; Use the first element of the accumulated list to hold the current running total
  ; And discard it at the end
  (cdr (foldr (lambda (n totals)
                (let ([new-total (+ (car totals) n)])
                  (list* new-total new-total (cdr totals))))
              '(0) 
              lst)))
```